# Rails: link_to do syntax - undefined method `stringify_keys' for #<Project:0x007fd223b0e9b8>

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I know there is a `link_to` syntax where you can add a bunch of html content in a `do` block to link. However, when I do the following:

```
= link_to 'Destroy', project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do
  %br Hello
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for #<Project:0x007fd223b0e9b8>
```

Does anybody know how to get around this issue?

Thanks!

p.s. here is the larger context of the View:

```
 - @projects.each do |project|
      %tr
        %td
          = link_to project.name, project
        %td
          = link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project)
        %td
          = link_to 'Destroy', project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do
            %br Hello
```

Comment: do I need to add `=` to the beginning of the `%br Hello` line so that that haml knows that we are still in the Rails loop?

Comment: I have a feeling that the problem is on the `project` variable. Did you check if it is not a typo? Like `@project` coming from the controller?

Comment: @MurifoX good question. No I edited the post to show its larger context :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a Path as second argument for the link_to, not an instanciated object.

Use the url helpers:

```
= link_to project_path(project), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do
  %br Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define name of the link inside the block like this:

```
= link_to project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do
  %br Hello
```

You can also use project_path(project) for link url. But a persisted instance variable with delete method will also go to destroy action. Have a try.

Answer (score 0):

Its either

```
link_to(url, html_options = {}) do
  # name
end
```

or

```
link_to(name, url, html_options = {})
```